# How to prevent future bookings in Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

When we are sharing our Google Calendar to allow others to book meetings with us, they can choose any free slot they like.

Today the date is March 12, 2021. The shared calendar gives them the option to book a time far into the future, say Jan 1, 2024.

Ideally, no one will do that.

I wish for my clients to book a time just a week into the future. Not beyond that. So how can I prevent future bookings OR how can I show available slots from today to 7 days from today?

Comment: How do you set you calendar to allow others to book meetings with you? Are you using *appointment slots*?

Comment: @Rubén I currently use a third party tool that is integrated with Google Calendar. The third party app doesn't have an option to limit slots as I mentioned. Previously, I used to make my Google calendar public and share it. In both scenarios, I have the same issue.